# Filter object keys beginning with a certain string

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have an object with these property keys:

```
instance['banana'];
instance['cl'];
instance['cl2'];
instance['minion'];
instance['cl3'];
```

I'd like to determine what is the highest number amongst the property keys beginning with `'cl'`. So of the filtered 'cl's, I want the 'cl' with the highest number in its key, not in its value. (In this example this would be 'cl3').

So far I'm able to access the `instance` property keys with `Object.keys(instance)`(of which I understand works in modern browsers only, but that's okay). Now I need to just filter out all `'cl'`s and then find out which number is highest.

I guess I should be looking at `Math.max` for finding out the highest number.

Any nudge in the right direction, por favor? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cls = Object.keys(instance).map(function(key){
  return /^cl/.test(key) && +key.replace(/\D+/,'');
});
//^= [false,"",2,false,3] == [0,0,2,0,3]

var maxCl = 'cl'+ Math.max.apply(0, cls); //= "cl3"
```

Comment: Sorry, @elclanrs. I think I might have been unclear. What I mean is of the filtered `'cl'`s, I want the `'cl'` with the highest number in its key. (In this example this would be `'cl3'`).